# Setting a default value for a one-on-one association

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, orm

Doctrine is a beast in combination with Symfony, but I can't seem to find good examples on how to achieve what I need.

My user schema is pretty standard. I want to set a [one-to-one association](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-one-unidirectional) that points to the forum permission a user has.

For this to work, I need to create a "default entity" that holds the default permissions given to the user upon creation.

Here is the User#forumPermission association

```
/**
 * @var $forumPermissions ?ForumPermission
 * One User instance has One Forum Permission instance.
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="ForumPermission")
 * @JoinColumn(name="forum_permission_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $forumPermission;

/**
 * @return ForumPermission
 */
public function getForumPermission() : ?ForumPermission
{
    return $this->forumPermission;
}

/**
 * @param ForumPermission $forumPermission
 */
public function setForumPermission(ForumPermission $forumPermission): void
{
    $this->forumPermission = $forumPermission;
}
```

This means the forum_permission table is empty at this time.
After that, I read in the doctrine docs that you can listen to all kinds of events related to flushing and persisting. Here is the docs sections for [`onFlush`](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/events.html#onflush)

This is what I came up with

```
public function onFlush(OnFlushEventArgs $eventArgs)
{
    $em = $eventArgs->getEntityManager();
    $uow = $em->getUnitOfWork();

    foreach ($uow->getScheduledEntityInsertions() as $entity) {
        /* @var $entity User */
        if (true === $entity instanceof User
        &&  null === $entity->getForumPermission()) {
            $entity->setForumPermission($this->getDefaultForumPermission($em, $uow));
        }
    }
}

private function getDefaultForumPermission(
    \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface $em,
    \Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork $uow)
{
    // Get the default permissions form the database
    $defaultForumPermission = $em->getRepository(ForumPermission::class)->find(1);

    // I will create a new entity if the default permissions do not exist
    if (null === $defaultForumPermission) {
        $defaultForumPermission = new ForumPermission();
        $uow->persist($defaultForumPermission);
        $uow->computeChangeSet($em->getClassMetadata('\App\Entity\ForumPermission'), $defaultForumPermission);
    }

    return $defaultForumPermission;
}
```

The docs aren't very clear on what you can do and where you should do it.
I figure I could do this all in the controller, but I like to keep everything where it belongs as intended by design.

So I'm wondering if this is the best way to do it, should I be doing this during prePersist or another event? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is you're listener actually getting run? Do you need to declare it in services.yml?

Comment: So you have new permission for every new user? Wouldnt be better to have many to one association to keep permission table smaller (a lot of user will have same permission, there could be like x thousands of users for 10 permissions)?

Comment: And for your case, you can add new default permission to constructor of user entity, it should persist.

Comment: No, i don't create a new permission entity for each user, that's what the default permissions entity with id 1 is for. If a user's permissions are changed, a new instance will be created. I can't set it in the constructor because i have to know if the `forumPermission` object is null, the default or a custom permissions object which can only be done if doctrine populated the user instance

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right, each time a `User` is created you want to create a new `ForumPermission` associated to this `User`. The best way to do it is to listen to the `prePersist` Doctrine event.

See https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html for additional information.